# How to get the first term of a Taylor Series?

Tags: series-expansion

How can I get the first non-zero term of a Taylor Series, when I don't know beforehand what power it will be?  Example:

```
Series[Sin[a]^6],{a,0,6}]
```

returns $a^6$, but I have to know the order is 6.  If I instead just say:

```
Series[Sin[a]^6],{a,0,1}]
```

I get back $O[a]^6$ but I don't know what command to use to extract the 6 from that to redo the Seres[] calculation.

The function I want would just work like this:

```
f[(Sin[a*Cos[a]]^7)*Cos[2a]^3]
```

$a^7$

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think your example `f[(Sin[Cos[a]]^7)*Cos[2a]^3]` is what you intended to write.

Comment: `but I don't know what command to use to extract the 6`  if you look at InputForm of what is returned from `Series` command, you'll see the form. Compare to what it says in help about it. It has all the info you want there.   Therefore `s = Series[Sin[a]^6, {a, 0, 6}]; s[[4]]` gives `6`.  Same for `s = Series[Sin[a]^6, {a, 0, 1}]; s[[4]]`

Answer (score 1):

`Asymptotic` (available from 12.1, I think) works for your first example:

```
Asymptotic[Sin[a]^6, a -> 0]
(* a^6 *)
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm running an older version, don't have that command.  Thanks anyway though.